# Twilio in-progress status callback for an incoming call

Tags: twilio, sinatra, webhooks, twilio-api

I'm using `twilio-ruby (5.15.1)`

My users call a Twilio phone number. Using the Incoming Call webhook my server picks up the call.

The Call Status Changes webhook is setup however that endpoint only receives `completed` statuses.

I'm interested in reacting to `in-progress` status but that never gets sent to my call status change endpoint.

I cannot execute the code I need to execute *after* the call starts, inside the incoming call webhook since the call status there is still `ringing`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the code that you need to execute after the call starts? I'd like to understand what the overall problem is before I answer.

Comment: I'd like to start a recording using REST API once the call begins.

Comment: Twilio call status changes is only triggered by twilio when the call ends. If you want to do an action when the call turn to in-progress, which is when twilio picked up the call that the user initiated, you just need to do it in the other webhook, the "a call comes in" webhook, which is after the call starts. If you want to play a recording, just return a Twiml with <play>recording url</play>

Comment: What are you trying to record? You can record a conversation when you use `<Dial>` or a message when you use `<Record>`. Why do you need the REST API for that?

Comment: @philnash my call handler `<Say>`s some instructions and then loops a sound using `<Play>`. A `<Record>` after that `<Play>` does not seem to have an effect. So I solved this by initiating the recording using the Rest API in a block executed 5 secs later but that's kind of a hack.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case then. Perhaps drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com describing what you are trying to achieve and we can discuss it further there and hopefully find you a solution.